# How can I make a time-relative mongodb view pipeline?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to make a mongodb view called "orders4H" that always returns documents from our "orders" collection that have a createdAt field value that is <= NOW-4hours. Then, any tool that is using the "orders4H" view as a collection source will always get the most current order data for the last 4 hours. The view creation requires an aggregation pipeline. However, I cannot figure out how to make a pipeline that will $match on a relative date.

In mongodb 4.2 they added an aggregation system variable called NOW which seems like it would be the thing to use, if only I could get it to work in a query document. I can use it to make new fields, for example, if I put timeNow: "$$NOW" in a $addFields stage, I get a new field with the current datetime. Now I want to use this "$$NOW" in a query evaluation.

Short version of question - how can I write a $match pipeline stage that will perform a server-time-relative comparison with a datetime field from the document?

MongoDB tickets imply that this support has been added ... but I cannot figure out how to use the $$NOW in a query. Anyone out there know how to do this?

Here are the relevant tickets that I found:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-37713
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23656

Answer (score 1):

With help from mongodb tech support, I was able to get a $match stage that works with mongodb 4.2 to make a time-relative query:

```
[ 
 { $match: 
  { $expr: 
   { $gt: [ 
    "$_created_at", 
     { $subtract: [ "$$NOW", 4 * 60 * 60 * 1000] } ] 
   } 
  } 
 }
]
```

Comment: The only downside to the use of $expr in the $match stage is that it does not use indexes, therefore this query takes a LONG time in our db that has 24M orders. In order to cull the data before applying the $expr, my full pipeline includes these stages as well:

```{$sort: {_created_at: -1}},{$limit: 50000}```